# How to get the coordinates of a square from 2 functions

Tags: functions

I have two functions, $y=3x^2$ and $y=- \frac 12 x^2$.

I want to get the coordinates of A from the ABCD square where A is the right point of the $y=3x^2$ function. I have tried to equalize the functions and everything but I cant get it.

The image is like this.

[image]

Comment: The function in the lower half of the graph doesn't match to any of the functions you wrote.

Comment: I think that the function of lower graph should be $y=-\frac{1}{2}x^2$ to perform the shape.

Comment: Sorry i edited the second function, now is well.

Comment: Sorry you are right, i forgot the ^2 of the second function. Also the ABCD square is complete.

Comment: @JonBasauri Then the equation to solve is $AB=AD$ where $AB=2x$ and $AD=\dots$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what you are exactly trying to do, but let me take a crack at it. We have $y=3x^2$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}x^2$, and we have a square whose sides are parallel to the two axes, and whose four vertices lie on the two parabolas, and we want to find the coordinates of the square. Now let us denote the point $A=(x,y)$ as you have in your picture the top right corner. Since this lies on the parabola $y=3x^2$, we can write $A=(x,3x^2)$. Now by the symmetry of the parabola, let us denote $B$ the upper left corner, then $B=(-x,3x^2)$. Now let us denote $l$ the length of the side of the triangle so we will have that $l=2x$. Now if we let $C=(-x,-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$ be the lower left corner, and then $D=(x,-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$ will be the lower right corner. Then We note that the length of the side $AD$ should be equal to $l$ as it is a square. Now the length of this will be $3x^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2=l=2x$. Thus, to solve for $x$, we must require that $(3+\frac{1}{2})x^2-2x=0$, or $x(\frac{7}{2}x-2)=0$, so we must have that $x=\frac{4}{7}$. Thus, we find that $A=(\frac{4}{7},3(\frac{4}{7})^2)$

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OP changed $f_2$ from $f_2(x) = -\frac{1}{8}x^2$ to $f_2(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2$. This changes my answer a bit, but OP should be able to follow the same logic to get their answer.

---

One function is $f_1(x)=y=3x^2$ and I'll assume the other is $f_2(x)=y=-\frac{1}{8}x^2$ because $4y=-\frac{1}{2}x$ seems wrong.

A square has four equal sides. Assuming the square is grid aligned, the four sides are at coordinates:

1. $(x_0, f_1(x_0)) = (x_0, 3x^2_0) = A$
2. $(-x_0, f_1(-x_0)) = (-x_0, 3x^2_0)$
3. $(x_0, f_2(x_0)) = (x_0, -\frac{1}{8}x^2_0)$
4. $(-x_0, f_2(-x_0)) = (-x_0, -\frac{1}{8}x^2_0)$

You also know the side length should be $2x_0$, so that means that you need $x_0$ such that the quantity $f_1(x_0) - f_2(x_0) = 3x^2_0 - (-\frac{1}{8}x^2_0) = 3x_0 + \frac{1}{8}x^2_0 = 3.125x^2_0$ equals $2x_0$. So solve for $x_0$ such that $3.125x^2_0 = 2x_0$.

Comment: Yes, i changed the question but the procedure is perfect, hope someone else will read the answer and understand it like i did. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Now find the coordinates of the rectangle with side lengths $s$ and $2s$ for some $s > 0$. Is there solution? no solutions? multiple solutions?